# java script error in throw exception

Tags: javascript, exception, throw

When i input some number it does not display any number. I am trying to insert this code on my [site](https://iccct.cricket/) but not working correctly . Please help me

```js
function myFunction() {
    var message, x;
    message = document.getElementBy("message");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    try { 
        if(x == "")  throw "empty";
        if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
        x = Number(x);
        if(x < 5)    throw "too low";
        if(x > 10)   throw "too high";
    }
    catch(err) {
        message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Please input a number between 5 and 10:</p>

<input id="demo" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Test Input</button>
<p id="message"></p>
```

Comment: `message = document.getElementBy`...what? Voting to close as typo.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: The error message says it all `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementBy is not a function`

Comment: By the way, you should use exceptions (errors) for exceptional circumstances. Bad user-entered data is not exceptional - its expected.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't selected the element correctly, it should say 
 `message = document.getElementById("message");`

Comment: no it should say `document.getElementById("message")`

Comment: I was referring to the end of that line.

Comment: @Jamiec in javascript it is `document.getElementById` why are you voting negative and saying worng answer

Comment: @almartinez firstly don't assume I voted at all. I didn't. And the answer *was* misinformation, so it deserved the downvote given.

Comment: @Jamiec no need to asume anything as the answer got one downvbote and you are the only commentor, anyway, don't downvote, correct him as we did, after you edited your comment

Comment: @almartinez once again. Not my downvote. Learn the ropes before accusing people.

Comment: @Jamiec whatever